# Disable shutdown on low battery

Tags: java, android, android-source

What command or app can i use to access the batteryservice.java to view the shutdownifnopower command to prevent the system from shutting down when the battery reaches 0%? (recalibration purposes)

Comment: No app or command can do that on standard phone. If you have the source you can compile the code and flash. If you don't but have root access, maybe decompile services.jar , modify the bytecode, and push it back to the phone